# Solve the following in non-negative integers: $3^x-y^3=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve the following in non-negative integers: $$3^x-y^3=1$$

Of course $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a trivial solution. After seeing that I proceeded like this:

$$3^x-y^3=1$$$$\implies3^x-1=y^3$$$$\implies2(3^{x-1}+3^{x-2}+ \cdots +3^1+1)=y^3$$$$\therefore2|y$$
So let $y=2k$ for non-negative $k$.
Then $$3^{x-1}+3^{x-2}+ \cdots +3^1+1=4y^3$$ So $4|LHS$ using a mod argument one can easily deduce that this implies that $x$ is even so let $x=2q$.

Then going back to our original expression we have $$9^q-1=8k^3$$$$\implies 9^{q-1}+9^{q-2}+ \cdots +9+1=k^3$$

Then again using mod arguments I deduced that $k \equiv 4 \pmod9$. And after that things started to get more and more yucky. This could be a completely bad approach so I also triad looking at $(y+1)(y^2-y+1)=3^x$ but that didn't lead me anywhere either.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Note the solution $x=2$, $y=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y+1=3^a$ with $a\ge1\iff y>1$

$y^2-y+1=3(3^{2a-1}-3^a+1)$ which can not be power of $3$ unless $2a-1=a\iff a=1$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If $d$ divides $y+1,y^2-y+1$ it will divide $y^2-y+1-y(y+1)=1-2y$

As $d$ divides $y+1,1-2y$ it will divide $2(y+1)+1-2y=3$

If $d=1,$ either $y+1=1$ or $y^2-y+1=1$ or both $=1$

If $d=3,$ either $y+1=3$ or $y^2-y+1=3$ or both $=3$